# Port forwarding doesn't work?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, modem

I set up a linux box a few days ago to host a web server (nginx). The site is ilan.duckdns.org, and I can connect to it fine using my local IP *as well as* the external IP. However, when I use canyouseeme.org to check whether the ports are forwarded, it says that the connection timed out. I asked my friends from abroad to test, and they can't connect to it either. I can use my phone's mobile network to connect to it fine, so I assume that anyone in my country (Israel) can see it just fine. Is this my ISP's fault or is it mine? It doesn't work for MC servers, or tf2 servers, or just about anything. Will replacing the modem work?

I have a Hotbox modem/router (2-in-1), I don't know if the problem is with it or something else. The box is connected to it via LAN cable on the 1st port. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j5uT.jpg) is a picture of my site working for me. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVfXu.jpg) is an photo of the (shoddy) port config of my router. My linux box's IP is 192.168.1.30.

Comment: Is `149.78.188.9` the IP that your modem/router gets on its WAN/Internet interface (if not, what is your IP)?  After a bit more digging, I'm wondering if your ISP is using Carrier-Grade NAT.

Comment: It doesn't say it on the config page.. Going on 'what is my IP' sites tells me it is it.

Comment: I realize that it is an old thread now. But I am facing the same problem with same ISP and same router. Does HOTNET block ports? I am trying to setup a Apache server but I cannot seem to successfully implement port forwarding. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this my ISP's fault or is it mine?

I had a look at your hotbox configuration.  I see that you have forwarded WAN requests on port 80 to port 8080 on your Nginx server, but I believe nginx listens on port 80 by default.  Unless I'm wrong or you've set that up yourself I would forward to port 80 on your nginx box instead.  Also, I'm assuming that the "0.0.0.0" addresses in the "external" column act as wildcards or something, which seems to be the case.  Also, your ability to establish a connection using your external (WAN) address means that your port forwarding is working properly on the boxes in which you tried that.  If we've addressed those items we can eliminate the hotbox as the culprit, because it doesn't know or care which country a request comes in from, it just waits for them and serves them to wherever it's supreme ruler (you) tell it.

> Will replacing the modem work?

Nope.  If you've got a 2-in-1 box then the modem is inside there too, and we already see that requests are making it through intact.

The question I would be asking at this point is why are requests from other countries not making it through.  I suspect the answer is that your ISP is interfering for some reason.  I would call them, politely ask to speak with a technical person and walk through the situation we've outlined with them.  If they are doing some kind of filtering intentionally, he will likely know exactly you're talking about, and whether or not he can do anything about it.

Best of luck,
Ryan

Comment: Thanks for the accept!  For the relief of everyone watching this thread, how did it turn out?

Comment: Replaced my modem/router, still no go. Currently on the phone with my ISP. It seems they hire brain-dead people to work as tech support.

Comment: apparently they "don't support servers". I had to wait 10 minutes on hold in order for their 'service rep' to google the answer to my question. What a bunch of dicks.

Comment: That’s really pointless, @Ubunfu. With carrier-grade NAT on the rise, they’ll just babble something about technical reasons. Also, you don’t pay for bandwidth or uplink or whatever but exactly for what’s specified in the contract. If it says incoming connections are blocked, they are. Period.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your ISP is blocking the traffic.  Here are the last few lines from a traceroute I did:

```
9    37 ms    34 ms    36 ms  he-0-10-0-1-pe03.1950stemmons.tx.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.86.114]
10    34 ms    39 ms    35 ms  173.167.57.146
11   188 ms   187 ms   188 ms  et-11-3-0.catania7.cat.seabone.net [93.186.129.223]
12   217 ms   225 ms   221 ms  hot.catania7.cat.seabone.net [93.186.129.237]
13   215 ms   218 ms   215 ms  mx-pt-ae7-vl18.hotnet.net.il [213.57.0.217]
14   211 ms   211 ms   212 ms  core-213-57-0-142.ptr.hotnet.net.il [213.57.0.142]
15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

As you can see the traffic gets to the "core" router on the hotnet network, and then stops there.  So, there is not much you can do.  Your best bet would probably be to find some cheap hosting somewhere and host your services there instead.

Comment: To be fair, traceroute not working doesn’t mean anything is blocked at all. It just means no TTL expired message was returned from wherever the packet died. You’d have to test the actual TCP connection.

Comment: It seems there's some kind of block somewhere. I just tried the following command (which sends TCP packets to port 80) and it fails: hping3 -p 80  ilan.duckdns.org (20 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss).

Comment: Strange, since it used to work a few months ago with my RPi... :/ I'll give them a call, thanks!